# Add Content type for Form Parameter in Loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I need to create a Form request where I need to upload a file as well as submit some json data into the request

Request should look like below

Although Im unable to find a way to pass content type into metadata form parameter

is there any way to fix this ?

```
web_submit_data("Create",
    "Action=URL",
    "Method=POST",
    "EncType=multipart/form-data",
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA,   
    "Name=metadata", "Value={\"type\":\"test\",\"name\":\"test.png\"}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=content", "Value=test.png", "FilePath=test.png", "File=yes",ENDITEM,  
    LAST);
```

Right now content is send as Content-Type: image/jpeg
metadata getting send with out content-type

Answer (score -1):

What have you tried?   These are all just strings that you can modify.

Comment: there is a validation from server side and it only accept content type json for metadata.due to that this request get failed.I need to specify Content-Type: application/json

Comment: Looking for something similar to this "Name=content", "Value={fileName}", "FilePath={fileName}", "File=yes","ContentType=image/jpeg" which can be used in metadata parameter as "ContentType=application/json"

Comment: Did you record this or build it from scratch?

Comment: tried both. and this an api request

Comment: It's a string.  Just modify directly.  Or, use a parameter to seed it (do not forget lr_eval_string() ).  Keep in mind that you may need to pass something in the header that is not present in the body.

Comment: looking for something similar to what we have in JMeter Content-Type Parameter in Parameters tab was able to successfully trigger the JMeter Request with that parameter for meta data form PARAM

Comment: It's just a string.  Either modify it directly or feed it from the parameter system.

Comment: There is no such parameter for web_submit_data can you send me sample request how it would look like

Comment: Just record it, with all headers, using proxy mode/external application, from another client.  I have no idea what the parameters are for your application and your request.

Comment: IT IS NOT ABOUT PARAMETERS WHAT I NEED IS A WAY TO PASS THE CONTENT TYPE FOR METADATA PARAMETER. SOMETHING SIMILAR TO THIS https://community.microfocus.com/adtd/loadrunner/f/sws-loadrunner_sf/193476/how-to-submit-request-payload-in-vugen/1593952#1593952

Comment: In JMeter there is way to pass Content-Type for Parameters I'm looking for same in Loadrunner

Comment: a)  I have no idea where your code originates from or whether it even matches what a client is trying to do. (b) I have suggested you take an existing client which produces the output you want, record it, with all headers, and modify this request.  This should have your field value already in place for mime type and headers (c) Anything in LoadRunner is a string.   Want to add a string, modify it.  Want to parameterize it, then take advantage of the parameter engine (d)  This advice is worth exactly what you paid for it.  (e) My experience? Continuous use of LoadRunner from 1996 until today.

Comment: You can record as web_custom_request() if you prefer a more raw view.  Or, you can record at Winsock for a very very low level view.  Or, you can record a GUI virtual user, operating a tool which generates your request.   And once you have any of them you can manipulate them to make the changes you so wish.